# .net - Get embedded resource path from Assembly

Tags: f#, .net-assembly

I've a .net6 F# solution with a test project.
The test project is in a folder named "MyProject.Core.Tests" and the project file is
**Core.UnitTests.fsproj**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>UnitTests.Core</AssemblyName>
    <!--DefaultNamespace>UnitTests.Core</DefaultNamespace-->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="aaa.txt"  />
```

In the solution the F# project is shown as "Core.UnitTests".  This is the MySolution.sln entry:

```xml
Project("{6EC3EE1D-3C4E-46DD-8F32-0CC8E7565705}") = "Core.UnitTests", "MyProject.Core.Tests\Core.UnitTests.fsproj", "{027C4CE5-B47B-4E4E-B7D2-477B4AB981F2}"
EndProject
```

In the project I have a file "aaa.txt" with BuildAction "Embedded Resource".

I try to read it with

```ml
module MyModule
  
  let assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  let assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name
  let stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assemblyName}.aaa.txt")
```

But stream is null.
If I print out "assemblyName" it is: **"UnitTests.Core".**
If I get all the resources within the Assembly using `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` I get **"Core.UnitTests.aaa.txt"** instead.

Why the resource is stored in "Core.UnitTests.aaa.txt" if the Assembly name is "UnitTests.Core" ?

It seems that the embedded resource path is generated using the project file name.
I also tried to set the `DefaultNamespace` in the project file but nothing changed.
How can I get the initial part of the resources from the Assembly?

### [EDIT]

I found this workaround:

```ml
module MyModule
  
  let nspace = assembly.GetExportedTypes().[0].Namespace
  let stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{nspace}.aaa.txt")
```

Not sure how to get the default namespace in a more clean way from F#  module (that code is not in a type/class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the resource name is qualified by the project's `RootNamespace`, rather than its `DefaultNamespace`, so this seems to work in the .fsproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>UnitTests.Core</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This is implemented by the [`CreateFSharpManifestResourceName`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/3bc41f9e10f9abbdc1216e984a98e91aad351cff/src/fsharp/FSharp.Build/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets#L95) build task.